# Create dict with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I would like to create this object with list comprehension:

```
{2012: 2012,
 2013: 2013,
 2014: 2014,
 2015: 2015,
 2016: 2016,
 2017: 2017,
 2018: 2018,
 2019: 2019,
 2020: 2020}
```

I tried:

```
In [59]: [{x: x} for x in range(2012,2020,1)]
Out[59]: 
[{2012: 2012},
 {2013: 2013},
 {2014: 2014},
 {2015: 2015},
 {2016: 2016},
 {2017: 2017},
 {2018: 2018},
 {2019: 2019},
 {2020: 2020}]
```

Which is not the exact output I need. I tried  `[dict(x: x) for x in range(2012,2020,1)]` as well but it this is invalid syntax. How do I achieve the result above?

Comment: list comprehensions will **always create lists**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list comprehension always creates a list. Use a dictionary comprehension to make a dictionary.

```
{x: x for x in range(2012, 2021)}
```

Note also that `range()` is exclusive of the ending value, so you need to use `range(2012, 2021)` if you want the last value to be `2020`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the desired output **by dictionary comprehension**

```
result = {x: x for x in range(2012, 2021)}
print(result)
>>> {2012: 2012, 2013: 2013, 2014: 2014, 2015: 2015, 2016: 2016, 2017: 2017, 2018: 2018, 2019: 2019, 2020: 2020}
```

if you want to do **with list comprehension**

```
d={}
[d.update({x: x}) for x in range(2012,2021)]
print(d)
>>> {2012: 2012, 2013: 2013, 2014: 2014, 2015: 2015, 2016: 2016, 2017: 2017, 2018: 2018, 2019: 2019, 2020: 2020}
```